# How to split the string if special character in string and keep the string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to split the string if special character in string and keep the string in same javascript?

Input:

```
Angular 6&Angular 9/Angular 10
```

output:

```
["Angular 6", "&", "Angular 9", "/", "Angular 10"]
```

Comment: jonrsharpe: this is not duplicate

Comment: the closing is from me. BTW, what have you tried and what does not work? what is a special character?

Comment: NIns: %,/,$,%....

Comment: in this case take the code from duplicate post and adjust for your need, like: `'Angular 6&Angular 9/Angular 10'.split(/([&\/])/)`